# SetHITTypeNotification does not take the Notification destination

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am using Mturk Sandbox environment. I have also created a queue (SQS) which will receive assignment submitted notification. I am trying to call SetHITTypeNotification API. But it always gives me following error

```
The value "https://sqs.XXXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX" is not valid for the parameter Destination.
```

I am sure I am providing the destination correctly. Can anybody suggest what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with `&Notification.1.Transport=Email` which needs to be passed along with the API URL.
I changed it to `&Notification.1.Transport=SQS` and it works like a charm.